# Ubuntu 16.04 is connected to wifi and ethernet but no internet

Tags: xubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04 is connected to wifi and ethernet but no internet
ubuntu wifi
I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 but I cannot connect to internet.

$ping 8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) BYTES OF DATA. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8 icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=10.3ms

Comment: So, you can ping to 8.8.8.8, indicating there is a network connection.  Would `ping askubuntu.com`also work? If yes, then you have internet access.  If no, there is a name resolution problem.  Could you then post the result of `ipconfig`